# eventlistener function definition

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I have the following code to setup my eventlistener (yes I know I should use delegation). The Function handler is normally anonymous, but I named it afterwards so I can remove it, but here the problems started. Here is the code:

```
for (var i=0;i<karten.length;i++) {
  setupeventlistener(karten[i]);
}

function setupeventlistener (obj){
obj.addEventListener("click",function handler(e){output(obj,e);});
}
```

Now if I want to remove the listener inside the output function (with `removeeventlistener("click",handler)` I can't access the handler function  because its in the `setupeventlistener` scope (that's what I guess?), but if I move it to the global scope and define it via var, it can't access the  argument obj (from `setuplistener`) which are passed to output.

In short, I want to remove the listener and keep all my function the way they are, because my little assignment works beside not being able to remove the listener to finish the project.

Comment: You should be able to move function handler() to the higher scope. Can you show what you mean with `access the handler arguments of output (obj)` ?

Comment: You can't remove event listeners if you don't have access to the original bound function.

Comment: @shilly, yes i can move it to global scope, but i dont know how to pass the argument (obj) which was passed to setupeventlistener to my handler aftwards. (when i put him into global scope). Am i right that the problem is that the function handler cant be accessed by any other function unless i put it into global scope?

Comment: The obj, will be the button/element clicked right? If so: `e.target` will also give you the element clicked, you don't actually have to pass the obj to the handler.

Comment: ok that was easy haha, thx :D, not sure why thought i had to pass the obj on top , since i was using e.target on most stuff anyway.

Comment: You could technically do `obj.myHandler = function(evt){/* access this*/; this.removeEventListener("click", this.myHandler);};`, then register `obj.myHandler` as listener.

Comment: @shilly thx it works , just changed every reference to e.target removed the obj argument and  added   // var handler = function (e) {output(e);};  //   to global scrope. Not sure why thought i had to pass the obj on top , since i was using e.target already in this function.

Answer (score 0):

this will help?

```
var list = {};

function set( obj, key )
{
    list[ key ] = Object.create(null);
    list[ key ].listener = function(e) { output( obj, e ) };
    list[ key ].target = obj;
    obj.addEventListener( 'click', list[ key ].listener );
}

function reset( key )
{
    list[ key ].target.removeEventListener('click', list[ key ].listener );
    delete list[ key ]
};

for (var i=0; i < karten.length; i++)
{
    set(karten[i], i );
}
```

Comment: i solved the problem by eliminating the obj argument and using e.target as shilly suggested, but i guess your answer is what i had in mind if i had to keep the obj argument for some specifc reasons. (i cant test the code now, but it makes sense, so i think it should work)